# Error: Bundler does not have write access to create a temp directory

Tags: ruby, bundler

When trying to run `bundle install` on a ruby project I received the following error:

```
There was an error while trying to write to `Bundler does not have write access
to create a temp directory within C:/Users/Simon/AppData/Local/Temp. Bundler
must have write access to your systems temp directory to function properly. `.
It is likely that you need to grant write permissions for that path.
```

I've checked the permissions in my temp folder and everything looks OK. Is there another possible cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

After much frustration, I discovered that this is actually a misleading error message. The actual error is `Errno::EACCES` which can be caused by several things: a file permissions error, or by a network connection permissions issue such as a firewall.

I my case, it was my **firewall**, TinyWall, that was blocking `ruby.exe` from connecting to the internet and thus causing this error. By giving it access through the firewall, `bundle install` ran successfully.

Just putting this out there for anyone else that may encounter this frustrating issue one day.